# De Morgan's law in Python not working as I think it should

Tags: python

So, De Morgan's law says that **not(A and B)** is the same as   **not A or not B**. When I tried to implement it using this code, it does not work. When I input a to be 3 and b to be 5, I get False in the output. What am I missing and how to do it the right way?

```
a = int(input("First num: "))
b = int(input("Second num: "))

print((not (a > 3) or not (b > 7))   ==  (not ((a <= 3) and (b <= 7 )) )  )
```

Comment: You're doing something like `not A or not B == not (C and D)` or even `not A or not B == not(not A and not B)`.

Comment: In your example what is `A` and what is `B`?

Answer (score 3):

A and B expressions in both statements should be the same.
Try changing

```
print((not (a > 3) or not (b > 7))   ==  (not ((a <= 3) and (b <= 7 )) )  )
```

to

```
print((not (a > 3) or not (b > 7))   ==  (not ((a > 3) and (b > 7 )) )  )
```

Answer (score 2):

As you said, De Morgan's law says that `not(A and B)` is the same as `not A or not B`. You are trying `not A or not B == not (C and D)`

This is DeMorgan's law.

```
a = int(input("First num: "))
b = int(input("Second num: "))

print((not (a > 3) or not (b > 7))==  (not ((a > 3) and (b > 7))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the low hanging fruit first: your statement is not actually expressing `not A or not B == not (A and B)`, but rather something like `not C or not D == not (A and B)`.

So, to test De Morgan's law, you would have to make sure that both `A` and `B` are the same on both sides of the comparison, for example:

```
(not (a <= 3) or not (b <= 7)) == (not ((a <= 3) and (b <= 7)))
```

Now, interestingly enough, the following two statements also hold:

```
not (a <= 3) == (a > 3)
not (b <= 7) == (b > 7)
```

So, alternatively, you could test the following:

```
((a > 3) or (b > 7)) == (not ((a <= 3) and (b <= 7)))
```